# Excel: find search 4 digits in a row and place them in other cell

Tags: excel, search, find, digits

I have an excel file with multiple columns (of course I can combine the whole row into 1 cell that is no problem if you got a solution for 1 cell only).

Some of these cells are empty, some contain text, some contain numbers, and some contain a mix.
I need to extract 4 digit number from them that is totally random. the there are no other 4digits numbers in a row so I don't have to worry about it

Comment: Could you post a small sample dataset of about 10 or so cell entries, preferably of sufficient variety so as to represent all the different types of strings we may be dealing with?

Comment: here is the csv (separated with semicolons) of 5 rows as an example. this data is almost the same as mine: 

    SHOP 1 MALVERN CENTRE; MAIN ROAD MALVERN; QUEENSBURGH; DURBAN;;;;; 80 Prince Alfred Street; cnr of Prince Alfred & Hunter Street; Durban;;;;;; Unit 4 Upton Park; 43 Sea Cow Lake Road; Springfield;;;;;; Airport Park; 2A Prospecton Road; Prospecton; Durban;4133;;;; Bluff;;;;;;;;

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are those five entries in five separate cells, e.g. A1:A5. Also, only one of those five entries contains a string comprising 4 digits. What exactly is your desired result?

Comment: yeah sorry im having a problem to post the example here never did this

Comment: http://pastebin.com/z6EipExG
Please check this link for an example of 10 rows

i have this in excel, and i want for example column Z to enter the found 4 digits number within the rest of the cells (about 8columns) for each row

Comment: If I place those 10 values in A1:A10 and give you a single formula to put in B1 which extracts the 4-digit value from A1 and which, when copied down, does a similar job for the strings in A2:A10, will you then be able to adapt that to meet your actual set-up?

Comment: i will be happy to get any help:) but will that work? having the data in a column not in a row is not a problem (i can have data in cells a1:a10 and the second record in b1:b10 and so on, if that is what you meant) the problem is that i need to extract 4 digits that are not always alone in a single cell, plus some cells might be empty in this a1:a10

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The formula in B1 would extract the 4-digit number from the text in A1. The formula in B2 would extract the 4-digit number from the text in A2. And so on. So if A1 contained: "Airport Park; 2A Prospecton Road; Prospecton; Durban;4133" the formula returns 4133. If there is no 4-digit number then the formula can return whatever you want. And I have no idea what you mean by "second record", sorry.